# CMD Subroutine Won't Abruptly End My Program As Intended

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

In the event that **`oldfile.txt`** does not exist, running this **[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** batch below, inexplicably ends up executing **line 8**, but I don't want it to!

I want the program to **`call the CheckErrorCondition`** subroutine and exit abruptly, because of the raised error in this case (I'm even force-simulating the error now).

The program still does not abruptly end on **lline 18** as I expect it to.

What am I doing wrong?

Here my **[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** batch script program:

```bat
 1    @echo off
 2    setlocal
 3    :: Rename a file
 4    ren "oldfile.txt" "newfile.txt"
 5    :: Call the subroutine
 6    call :CheckErrorCondition
 7    :: Delete the file
 8    del "newfile.txt"
 9    :: End of script
10    endlocal
11    goto :eof
12    :CheckErrorCondition
13    :: Simulate an error condition
14    set errorCondition=true
15    :: Check the condition using if-else
16    if %errorCondition%==true (
17          echo Error condition detected. Exiting...
18          exit /b 1
19        ) else (
20          echo Condition is not an error. Continuing...
21        )
22    goto :eof
```

Comment: Thanks. Does my problem description make more sense now?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that exit /b only exits the subroutine and not the whole program. To exit the whole program abruptly, I'll have to add the following line right after line 6 (in effect a second exit statement):

```
if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /b %errorlevel%
```